# AngularJS - HTML losing scope on template replace in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have the following code in my html.

```
<div id="section">
  <div new-exercise ng-repeat="section in sections track by $index">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="add_exercise add_exercise_btn">
  <a class="add_exercise_link" ng-click="addExercise()">
    <span>+ Add an Exercise</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

the method `addExercise()` adds a new element to the variable sections, hence updating the html with another template (represented by directive `new-exercise`).

i.e.

```
$scope.addExercise = function(){
  $scope.sections.push({
    title: "hello",
    content: "fsa"
  });
}
```

**The directive `new-exercise`:**

```
.directive('newExercise', function () {
  return {
      templateUrl: '/templates/exercise-form.html',
      replace: true,
  }
})
```

**The template `exercise-form.html`:**

```
<div class="add_exercise" id="add_exercise_form" data-section-id="{{id}}">
<form class="new_section">
    <div class="input-box">
      <input id="title"  type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{section.title}}" ng-model="section.title">
      <label for="title">Exercise Name</label>
      <span class="help-block"></span>
      <span>{{ section.title }}</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I expect the template `exercise-form.html` to update the value inside input to be `hello` but the scope is empty.

However, if I remove the directive and add the template html under ng-repeat it works as I expect. I feel that the scope is lost due to directive, but not so sure about the exact reason. Can anyone explain me the reason and how to resolve?

Thanks.

Comment: try removing the replace=true in your directive?

Comment: Tried it. But didn't make any difference.

Comment: @kukkuz That worked. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `replace: true` in your directive.

Corrected directive given below:

```
.directive('newExercise', function () {
  return {
      templateUrl: '/templates/exercise-form.html'
  }
})
```